# HTML tree full width hover effect

Tags: html, css

I have an html tree which is mostly consisting of nested unordered lists.

I need to create a full width hover effect for each leaf, something similar with windows file menu tree hover effect.

[image]

The hover effect is a `<div/>` with a background-color and a border.

I have made a hack which simulates the full width, but the sideways borders aren't visible anymore.

Is there a CSS trick that i can use in order to also keep the sideways borders of the hover effect and still have full width?

I have made a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L8eSr/) example, so is easier to understand.

**Note:**
I can't change the html tree structure or css because it is created by a third party plugin (kendo ui treeView), so i need to find a solution using what i have.

**CSS:**

```
h6 { font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 0; }

.tree { width: 300px; border: 1px solid #000; padding: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px; }
.tree ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none; }
.tree ul li { padding-left: 16px; }

.tree li .item { position: relative; }
.tree li .item .overlay
{ position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background-color: #C5E7E6; display: none; border: 1px solid red; }
.tree li .item:hover .overlay { display: block; }

/*Full width hack*/
.tree.fullWidth { overflow: hidden; }
.tree.fullWidth li .item .overlay { left: -100px; width: 1000px; }
```

**HTML**

```
<h6>Normal overlay - not full width</h6>
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="item">
                Node 1
                <div class="overlay"></div>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="item selected">
                        Node 2
                        <div class="overlay"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<h6>Full width overlay (but side borders aren't visible anymore)</h6>
<div class="tree fullWidth">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="item">
                Node 1
                <div class="overlay"></div>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="item selected">
                        Node 2
                        <div class="overlay"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution changing only the part of the CSS under "hack". *I assume that at least you can change that*

CSS

```
/*Full width hack*/
.tree.fullWidth { overflow: hidden; }
.tree.fullWidth li .item .overlay { right: -8px; width: 314px; left: auto !important; }
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/L8eSr/1/)

If the tree has a variable width, this is better:

```
.tree.fullWidth li .item .overlay { 
    right: -8px; 
    width: 300px;
    padding-left: 14px; 
    left: auto !important; 
}
```

It works exactly like the other version, but now the width is the same that the tree width, so the Javascript doesn't need to set a *magic* width (that you don't know from where it comes:

Comment: It works with a fixed width. The tree has variable width. However, i'll use some javascript to set the width of the overlays when the tree is loaded

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem as you, after some trying and testing I came up with this. It allows you to add scrollbars and put the padding on the inner .

**HTML**

```
<div class="tree" style="width:256px; height:256px;">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</span></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</span></div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</span></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tree {
    position:relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #8B9097;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-left:200px;
    /*! margin-left: just for testing */
}
.tree > div {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    min-width:100%;
}
.tree * {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.tree ul {
    margin:0;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.tree li > div {
    position:relative;
    margin-left:-100000px;
    padding-left:100000px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    display:block;
}
.tree li div:hover {
    background-color: #B6BABF;
    color: #fff;
}
.tree li.collapsed > ul {
    display:none;
}

.tree li.expanded > ul {
    display:inherit;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WknDZ/17/

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation few days ago.

Heres 1 way to approach it ( assuming you've got full control over the HTML )

**HTML**

```
<div class="tree relative">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <span class="relative">Node 1</span>

            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="item selected">
                        <div class="overlay"></div>
                        <span class="relative">Node 2</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.relative {
    position:relative;
}

.tree { 
    width: 300px; 
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    padding: 10px; 
    margin-bottom: 15px; 
}

.tree ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none; }
.tree ul li { padding-left: 16px; }

/*.tree li .item { position: relative; }*/

.tree li .item .overlay { 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0; 
    right:0;
    /*
    top: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    */
    height:26px; /* well, thats a bummer */
    background-color: #C5E7E6; 
    display: none; 
    border: 1px solid red; 
}
.tree li .item:hover .overlay { display: block; }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/5fKP4/2/

Comment: Your solution works pretty well, but unfortunately, `.tree li .item` needs to have relative position (otherwise i break the tree layout)